# como obtener id de una session con php

Tags: php, javascript

que tal estoy tratando de obtener mi ID por medio de una consulta
es decir mi login tiene como objetivo si se inicio sesion muestrame los campos y si no muestrame el boton iniciar sesion
entonces quiero agregar un boton editar cuenta
pero no me toma el id
entonces lo que requiero es que se tome el id para yo hacer el update
este es mi codigo

```
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['usuario'])) {
       echo'<a class="btn btn-primary" href="logeo.php" role="button" style=" position:absolute;  rigth:63%;
       top:1%;">INISIAR SESION</a>';

    
}else{
    echo "<center><h4 class='tabita'>". "Bienvenido\ a: " . $_SESSION['usuario'] ."<br> " .$mensaje. "</h4></center>" . "\n\n";
    echo'<a class="btn btn-primary" href="logout.php" role="button" style=" position:absolute;  rigth:63%;
       top:1%;">Cerrar Sesion</a>';


       $sqlos = "SELECT id FROM useros WHERE usuario='" . $_SESSION['usuario'] ."'";
       $resultes = mysqli_query($link, $sqlos);
       $fila2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultes);
      

echo "<center><a class='btn btn-info' href='upd1.php?id='".$fila2["id"]."alt='edit'>Editar mi Perfil</a>";

}

 var_dump($fila2);
```

aqui muestro como me aparecen los campos cuando trato de tomar el id de usuario logeado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

muestra de $fila2['id']
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

var_dump($fila2["id"]);

Comment: Podrias hacer un $fila2["id"]

Comment: ya--- esta en la pregunta

Comment: donde esta el botón de editar mi perfil, ahi quieres imprimir lo que esta dentro de ese array?

Comment: si es decir ese boton me manda a un update

Comment: Pero ese código de array te lo muestra porque tiene un var_dump() ? para que quieres mostrar el ID si ya lo has puesto en el href del boton?

Comment: porque no me esta dando el id por eso agrege la imagen donde se ve el resultado de id dice 
aqui muestro como me aparecen los campos cuando trato de tomar el id de usuario logeado

Comment: Puede poner ese var_dump() en tu publicación pero como texto

Comment: si esta hasta el final el  var_dump($fila2);
y el de  var_dump($fila2["id"]);

Comment: Me refería a la respuesta que esta impresa en la imagen, pero en tu href hace faltan colocar una comilla simple 
`href='upd1.php?id=".$fila2["id"]."'`

Comment: me manda id='' nda

Comment: Coloca exactamente esto 
`echo "<center><a class='btn btn-info' href='upd1.php?id=".$fila2["id"]."' alt='edit'>Editar mi Perfil</a>";`

Comment: Si el usuario ya tiene sesión activa, no es necesario que envíes su ID por parámetro, deja el enlace solo con `href="upd1.php"` y en `upd1.php` haces la consulta para obtener los datos que necesites.

Comment: a ya quedo gracias

Comment: pero me lo manda como string lo que queria es que mandara por int porque en mi otra pagina update.php me manda 
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot access offset of type string on string in C:\xampp\htdocs\empleo\upd1.php:37 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\empleo\upd1.php on line 37

Comment: `$fila2['id']` se entiende que es un número edita tu pregunta y arregla el código de esa página  eso es otro error, Recuerda que si lo estas enviando el `$fila2['id']` por la `URL` tiene que recogerlo con un `$_GET['id']` en la otra página